Azue Devops ManaulValidation task
In my Azure DevOps, ManualValidation task is not found!
I did search in extensions but seems it is not normal extension, even ManualIntervention, which is exist, also not exist as extension.
And when tried I got different error which is "The given key release.releaseId is not found in the dictionary"
Below is the yaml I used.
jobs:
- job: doSomething
  displayName: Do Something
  steps: 
  - script: echo Hello World!
    displayName: 'run a one line script'

- job: waitForvalidation
  displayName: wait For External Validation
  dependsOn: doSomething
  pool: server
  timeoutInMinutes: 15
  steps: 
  - task: ManualIntervention@8
    inputs:
      instructions: "please validate"
      emailRecipients: 'my-mail'
      onTimeout: reject
- job: doSomethingAfterValidation
  displayName: Do Something After Validation
  dependsOn: waitForvalidation
  steps: 
  - script: echo Deploy to prod!
    displayName: 'run a one line script'


The Manual Validation task and the Manual Intervention task are not extensions but tasks.
It is noted in the Manual Intervention task that

This task is intended for use in a classic release pipeline.  For YAML usage, see Manual Validation task.

So you can use the Manual Validation task in your yaml.
Yaml sample:
jobs:
- job: doSomething
  displayName: Do Something
  steps: 
  - script: echo Hello World!
    displayName: 'run a one line script'

- job: waitForValidation
  displayName: Wait for external validation
  pool: server
  timeoutInMinutes: 4320 # job times out in 3 days
  steps:
  - task: ManualValidation@0
    timeoutInMinutes: 1440 # task times out in 1 day
    inputs:
      notifyUsers: |
        test@test.com
        example@example.com
      instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume'
      onTimeout: 'resume'
- job: doSomethingAfterValidation
  displayName: Do Something After Validation
  dependsOn: waitForvalidation
  steps: 
  - script: echo Deploy to prod!
    displayName: 'run a one line script'

Test result:

Update:
Test the issue on Azure DevOps Server 2020.1.2:

It is mentioned in the release note of Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.2 :

Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.2 is a roll up of bug fixes. You can directly install Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.2 or upgrade from Azure DevOps Server 2020.


but why i can't see manualValidation task listed in my tfs !! how to add it ?

Hi @moshahen, which TFS version you are using? I tested the task in Azure DevOps server 2022 and it works without problem.

our running version is Version Dev18.M170.8

Hi， it seems you are using the Azure DevOps server 2020. I installed the Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.2 from the download page and found it contains the ManualValidation@0 task. Can you update to the Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.2?

Hi @moshahen,  I updated the answer with the screenshot of my Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.2.

thank you very much, it is working after upgrade :)

Hi @moshahen, thanks for your update and happy to hear that it is working after upgrade! Happy coding!
